# Java volatile key word senseless for some types?

Tags: java, types, keyword, volatile

I read that reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double). So my question is: Is there a situation where it makes sense to declare a `volatile int i;` or a `volatile Object o;`?

This is not a duplicate because my question is whether it's senseless for some types, and if not, why? I know that there are cases where you need it / where it makes sense (for double and long) and I can't find an explanation in the other thread where the difference is between `volitile int i` and `int i` (reads and writes are atomic in both cases). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html I am rather looking for an expanation why it wont work without the volatile keyword, not for cases where I should use it.

Comment: Atomicity and visibility are two different things.

Comment: @Kayaman Where exactly is the difference? Can you give me an example where it wont work without volatile using an int, boolean, ...? And why it wont work.

Comment: @stonar96 click the link to the duplicate question, and read. It has explanations, examples, everything.

Comment: @JBNizet I can only find explanations like: "the reading threads are guaranteed to see the latest value written to the volatile variable. Without making the variable volatile, this would not be guaranteed." But why wouldn't it be guaranteed? When I set a `boolean b = false;` to `true` in the mainthread and after setting `b` i read it from another thread, wouldn't it read `true` then? There is no race conditions as writing to a boolean is atomic

Comment: Oh I think I have got it. It's because the CPU works with cached values and you can prevent that the CPU uses cached values with the volatile keyword. Correct? So in my example in the above comment it is not guaranteed that the other thread reads true (If false is still cached).

Comment: It wouldn't be guaranteed because in a multi-core architecture, each core has its own cache, and one thread could thus read a stale value from its cache, instead of reading the up-to-date value written by another thread, in another core cache. The point of volatile is precisely to provide a visibility guarantee.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it.